# Manually configure ipv6 address in 2 different subnets

Tags: ipv6

I have a following setup

```
 Linux1---------------Linux2------------------Linux3
(eth0)            (eth1)     (eth0)           (eth0)
```

I have this in a local network i.e the Ethernet cables are connected directly.I am configuring the IPV6 address for the first time. 
I want `Linux1(eth0)` and `Linux2(eth1)` to be in one `ipv6 subnet` and `Linux2(eth0)` and `Linux3(eth0)` in a different `ipv6 subnet`.

After going through this link `http://techxcellence.net/2011/05/09/v6-subnetting-made-easy/`
i chose the following

For Linux3 eth0

```
   ifconfig eth0 add 2002:db8:c001:ba40::/58
```

For Linux 2 eth0

```
   ifconfig eth0 add 2001:db8:c001:ba40::/58
```

I am not sure if this is correct. the intention is to have 2 different ipv6 addresses in the same ipv6 subnet. I am guessing we can change any bit in the prefix.

Is my understanding correct?

The ipv6 address in the other subnet would be

```
2002:db8:c001:ba00::/58 and 2001:db8:c001:ba00::/58?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When subnetting you define a fixed *start* of the address prefix. You then give addresses within that prefix (so with the same start) to your devices. So you don't use `2001:…` and `2002:…`, but you use e.g. `2001:db8:c001:ba40::1` and `2001:db8:c001:ba40::2`.

Subnets in IPv6 are always a `/64`. (well, there are cases like point-to-point and loopback interfaces where you might want to use something else, but let's keep it simple for now) That means that the first 64 bits of the address are fixed and the remaining bits (128 - 64 = 64) are available to number your devices with.

The addresses you use (from `2001:db8::/32`) are only for documentation purposes. To determine which addresses you can use you ask your ISP (if your ISP provides IPv6) or you generate a ULA prefix (private addresses, not usable on the internet). Sites such as [SixXS](https://www.sixxs.net/) provide a [ULA generator](https://www.sixxs.net/tools/grh/ula/) that you can use.

You usually get a `/48` prefix. For example my home network has `2a00:8640:1::/48`. That means that I can use `2a00:8640:1:0000::/64` to `2a00:8640:1:ffff::/64` to number my subnets. When building a network such as described in your example I could do something like:

- Linux1 eth0: `2a00:8640:1:a::1/64`
- Linux2 eth1: `2a00:8640:1:a::2/64`
- Linux2 eth0: `2a00:8640:1:b::1/64`
- Linux3 eth0: `2a00:8640:1:b::2/64`

You can do the same with your own IPv6 addresses.